# Porting and Messaging between Mac Catalyst App and Chrome Extension

Tags: ios, safari-extension, mac-catalyst

We have a Mac Catalyst app that is installed and works with a custom Safari extension. The Safari is working as expected and is able to pass messages (using sendNativeMessage) to the Mac Catalyst app as expected. Now we want to port the extension to Chrome and other browsers on the desktop and retain the ability to pass messages back and forth.

My questions:

Is it possible ?
Can we pass messages form the Chrome extension and the Mac Catalyst app?
How do we distribute/install the Chrome extension?
Can we have the extension running in parallel across multiple browsers and still communicate the Mac Catalyst app ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Chrome Extensions specifically but you should be able to implement support for them the same way you would for an AppKit app.